# SQL Server 2008 Express Install Location

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008, web-platform-installer

MS insisted on installing this via the Web Platform Installer.  Now I want to install it again, but I don't want to download it again.  Any ideas wheere the install file is located, if anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/06/15/installing-sql-server-2008-guidance.aspx) MS Article you need to download a separate installer from any of the links provided on the page. From [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/604/troubleshoot-microsoft-web-platform-installer-issues/) page there is a way to clean the cache folder, listed rather close to the bottom of the page, and this may be a guide to where the installation files are kept, although I can recall at one stage the installer delete successful packages once installed. I can't confirm if it uses the standard installer or a specialized one for the platform installer itself.

According to Scott Gu's blog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/06/02/microsoft-web-platform-installer.aspx) it is mentioned that the Web Platform installer uses special MSDeploy packages to deploy software, so chances are you won't be able to use the same installer outside of the Web Platform. The comments contain some information on this in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, as Diago suggested, it may not be present on the machine now. (Since it may be deleted after successful installation.)

One thing you can do is download the full installer for SQL 2008 SP1 Express from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/06/15/installing-sql-server-2008-guidance.aspx).
You need not run the web installer again & again in the future. (But you WILL need to do one more download now :()

Comment: That link is no longer available.

Comment: Sry, a fullstop was added at the ned of the url. Edited it.